# Rails 4- Ransack with collection_select - how to display names in collection rather than ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails

- i am trying to use ransack to search through a list of socials via the category age.
- I have successfully managed to do this but the id of the listed ages are appearing rather than the name
- to make it more will list what have within my file

> schema

```
socials
t.string   "title"
t.text     "description"
t.string   "address"
t.integer  "category_age_id"

category_ages
t.string   "name"
```

> seed.rb

```
CategoryAge.delete_all
ca01 = CategoryAge.create!(name:'18 - 24')
ca02 = CategoryAge.create!(name:'25 - 34')
ca03 = CategoryAge.create!(name:'All Ages')
```

> model

```
social.rb
belongs_to :category_age

category_age.rb
has_many :socials
```

> controller

```
socials_controller.rb
def index
 @search = Social.search(params[:q])
 @socials = @search.result(distinct: true)
 @age = Social.find_by_sql("SELECT category_age_id FROM socials GROUP BY category_age_id").map &:category_age_id
end
```

> views

```
views/socials/index.html.erb
Age Group: <%= f.select :category_age_id_eq, @age %>
```

i have tried the below code in the views/social/index.html.erb file but no success

```
Age Group: <%= f.select :category_age_name_eq, @age %>
```

my ransack works perfectly but how do i make the name of the category to display rather than the id. The image attached show the ids, but would like to see for example 18 - 24. Your help would be much appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways to do this, but I like to use `options_for_select` and pass it a two dimensional array where the the first value is the value to save and the second is what you'd like to show show. So something like,

```
 <%= f.select :thing, options_for_select([[value_to_save, value_to_show], [another_to_save, another_to_show], [etc, etc]] %>
```

I'd write a method that passes the array of arrays and pass it to `options_for_select`

Comment: Thank you soo much!